# JetBrains IDEs (WebStorm, IntelliJ, Pycharm. etc...) are not saving password for Bitbucket

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working in a Bitbucket repo via WebStorm, using git. At every operation (push, pull, etc...), it asks me to re-enter the credentials, though I've selected to remember them. It seems to be an old bug... that should have been resolved so far:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162522

Nothing of the answer to the post helped me to solve the problem. The strangest thing is that in other computers the repo seems to work well (in more than one JetBrains IDE), when here on the contrary it doesn't work neither on WebStorm nor on IntelliJ (and PyCharm)!

Do you know a solution, or at least a workaround to the problem?

I've signaled the whole thing to jetbrains too:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31245

And found a strange line in the log

```
2018-02-14 09:33:41,249 [ 554975] INFO - #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: UriFormatException
```

Comment: what is your `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Password` value? what OS are you on? Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183847 - does it look similar?

Comment: The setting is right, I've checked save passwords in KeePas. I'm on Windows 10. No, your link doesn't seem to look similar.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) to it

Comment: 2018-02-14 09:33:41,249 [ 554975]   INFO -  #git4idea.commands.GitHandler - fatal: UriFormatException encountered. 

I think is this the problem

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have resolved. In other PCs and IDE, I've setted the address of repo copying it from address bar of browser, for example:

https://bitbucket.org/NickName/tests

and it worked!!
But for some reason, in my case it only accepts the "rigorous" git address:

https://mynick@bitbucket.org/NickName/tests.git

and with this works with no problem.